# custom loading indicater in ios

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, loading, uiactivityindicatorview

How to create custom loading indicator,and it'll need to fill according to response coming form server.
As per my requirement I'm attaching the image,How I need to implement the same.Please suggest
me.

**Custom Image :**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87eqa.png]

Comment: means your question about progressbar ?

Comment: Yes. progressbar I need to show that for loading.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984690/creating-a-custom-progress-bar-with-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont want to write you own custom control, you can use some of this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress

otherwise you need to implement by yourself

[link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mnmprogressbar) or [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ylprogressbar) - for you image

Comment: Thank you very mush.These links are helpful for what exactly for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **Custom Progress Bar** then you should Check the Answer by **Grady Player** in this SO Question: [Creating a custom progress bar with images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5984933/1603072).

**Some More Useful Links :**

1. [UIProgressView and Custom Track and Progress Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980891/uiprogressview-and-custom-track-and-progress-images-ios-5-properties?rq=1).
2. [Customized Progress Bar](http://code4app.net/ios/Customized-Progress-Bar/4f7d21ea6803fae66d000001).

**Best Link :** [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=progress)